# New environment special colored box

Tags: color, boxes

I would like to construct a new environment that I can call like:

```
\begin{Box}{*Title of Box*}

** Text **
** Math equations **

\end{Box}
```

It shall have the following properties:

- The box background shall have a colour.
- The text inside the box shall have a distance of 3 - 5 mm to the boundary.
- Important:
  It shall **break at the end of a page** and continue at the next page.

Is there someone who can do that?

Comment: Use the package tcolorbox.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How wide should be color box be?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with `tcolorbox`, one of my favourite packages (;-))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Define a new box for this
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{MyBox}[2][]{%
  title={MyBox \thetcbcounter\ #2},
  boxsep=1mm,
  colback=white!40!yellow,
  breakable,
  #1
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{MyBox}{My nice title box}

\blindtext

$E=mc^2$

\blindtext[3]



\end{MyBox}


\begin{MyBox}[width={0.5\textwidth},coltitle={blue}, colbacktitle={gray},colback={green!60!blue}]{My nice title box, but not so wide}

\blindtext

$E=mc^2$

\blindtext[3]



\end{MyBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]